# How to pass a pointer to class's pointer attribute as a double pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters

I cant figure out how to properly pass this double pointer.... nothing i've tried works...

```
class myClass{

    MyClass *attribClass;
}

void derp(MyClass **myA) {
    // recursively calls down classes....
    derp(&(myA->attribClass)); // what am i doing wrong?
}

int main() {

    MyClass *myClass = new MyClass;

    myClass.attribClass = *whatever code to initialize a long linked list of MyClass's*;

    derp(&myClass); 
}
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to [solve the impossible half of your problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/10/30/5773153.aspx)?

Comment: building a binary search tree insert method in butchered C style C++ :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several issues:

```
class MyClass {  //  Change to "MyClass".

public:   //  Need to make it public or it can't be accessed by "derp()"
          //  Did you intend "derp()" to be a class member?

    MyClass *attribClass;
}; //  missing semicolon

void derp(MyClass **myA) {
    // recursively calls down classes....
    derp(&((*myA)->attribClass)); // what am i doing wrong?
}
```

And in the last one, you need to deference `myA` once before you access `attribClass`.

```
derp(&((*myA)->attribClass)); // what am i doing wrong?
```

Comment: Also note that the variable has a bad type, it should be 'myClass' not 'MyClass'

Comment: OMG... how did I miss that?!?! Nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

`myA` is a pointer to a pointer, so you need to dereference it to get a pointer which you can use `->` with, so:

```
derp(&(myA->attribClass));
```

Should be

```
derp(&((*myA)->attribClass));
```

I'm assuming you need to change/set the value of the pointer.  If you aren't you probably shouldn't use a double pointer here.

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra dereference on `myA`, which is of type `MyClass **` (not simply `MyClass *`):

```
derp(&(*myA)->attribClass);
```